# Como abrir un documento con OpenFileDialog y copiarlo en portapapeles con Clipboard?

Tags: c#, archivo, aplicación-escritorio

La idea es que al presionar un botón se abra un cuadro de dialogo para seleccionar un archivo que al mismo tiempo sea copiado en portapapeles. Además al completar dicha acción que el nombre del archivo sea agregado a un listbox, y así con todos los archivos que seleccione y copie.
El objeto de esto es luego poder pegar los archivos en wpp web sin tener que buscar uno por uno, yo en el programa tendria una grilla con registros que hacen referencia a esos archivos, lo ideal seria hacer clic derecho en el registro, copiar, y que el archivo al que se hace referencia sea copiado en portapapeles.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el recorrido inicial para elaborar una [buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Agrega el código que has intentado.